# application.yaml files for starting some Spring Boot applications

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, yaml

I want to start my app.jar (Spring Boot) using other properties by providing some yaml files e.g. in folders

```
/opt/app/app1/application1.yaml
/opt/app/app2/application2.yaml
/opt/app/app3/application3.yaml
```

Each yaml is for one app configuration.

Is there any way to give the new application.yaml as a parameter after the jar sth. like:

```
java -jar /opt/app/app.jar /opt/app/app3/application1.yaml
java -jar /opt/app/app.jar /opt/app/app3/application2.yaml
java -jar /opt/app/app.jar /opt/app/app3/application3.yaml
```

We start our application by using the PropertiesLauncher with -cp

```
java -Xmx4096M -cp /opt/app/app.jar -Dloader.path=additional-libs/ -Dloader.main=app.SpringBootApplication org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Comment: Now what if there would be some official documentation, which would explain [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files)...

Comment: I was there but I do not know how to specify /opt/app/app3/application1.yaml

Comment: Read the docs it explains it, which properties to pass.

Comment: now the Spring Boot application has a problem by loading class from lib folder (BOOT-INF\lib\ some JAR there). But this issue happens only if I load the application.yaml from a docker volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java -jar /opt/app/app.jar --spring.config.additional-location=/opt/app/app3/application3.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

[official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files) explains exactly your case.

```
java -jar /opt/app/app.jar --spring.config.location=/opt/app/app3/application3.yaml
```

Comment: What is about using
java -Xmx4096M -cp /opt/app/app.jar -Dloader.path=additional-libs/ -Dloader.main=app.SpringBootApplication org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher --spring.config.location=/opt/app/app3/application3.yaml

Comment: --spring.config.location does not only override the Spring properties from BOOT-INF\classes\ it also disables all of them. So properties BOOT-INF\classes\application.yml are not considered any more, and only the properties in /opt/app/app3/application3.yaml are considered

See my comment above:
 now the Spring Boot application has a problem by loading class from lib folder (BOOT-INF\lib\ some JAR there) ...

Comment: spring.config.additional-location  is what I need